# Float if statement returns error with || in swift

Tags: swift, if-statement, xcode6

So here is my if statement:

```
if !DAGNViewControllerInstance.DValueVar<=5 || !DAGNViewControllerInstance.DValueVar>=1 || !DAGNViewControllerInstance.AValueVar<=6 || !DAGNViewControllerInstance.AValueVar>=2 || !DAGNViewControllerInstance.GValueVar<=3 || !DAGNViewControllerInstance.GValueVar>=2 || !DAGNViewControllerInstance.NValueVar<=3 || !DAGNViewControllerInstance.NValueVar>=1 || !DAGNViewControllerInstance.TValueVar<=9999 || !DAGNViewControllerInstance.TValueVar>=1 {

        self.ErrorField.text = "One or more values are not in range!"
        }
```

This if statement checks a variable to see if it is in range or not. But whenever I try to build the code I get an error from this if statement.

`Swift Compiler Error Cannot Invoke '||' with an argument list of type '($T88, $T96)'`

The ValueVars are floats. The DAGNViewControllerInstance is a instance of this UIViewController subclass:

```
import UIKit
extension String {
var floatValue: Float {
    return (self as NSString).floatValue
}
}
class DAGNViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var DValue: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var AValue: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var GValue: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var NValue: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var TValue: UITextField!
var DValueVar: Float = Float()
var AValueVar: Float = Float()
var GValueVar: Float = Float()
var NValueVar: Float = Float()
var TValueVar: Float = Float()

@IBAction func GOButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    DValueVar = DValue.text.floatValue
    AValueVar = AValue.text.floatValue
    GValueVar = GValue.text.floatValue
    NValueVar = NValue.text.floatValue
    TValueVar = NValue.text.floatValue
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

The Value IBOutlets are linked to UITextFields. The if statement is in another UIViewController subclass which is the custom class of a UIView in the storyboard which has a label that I want to display the error message.

Does anyone know why I get the error, and or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably with the order of operator application, combined with the ambiguity of the numeric literals (which could be floats, doubles, integers etc).  For example, in a simpler case:

```
let d = 12.3
let e = 45.6

// error: cannot invoke '>=' with an argument list of type '($T6, $T12)'
if !d>=3 || !e>=4  { }

// compiles without error
if !(d>3) || !(e>=4) { }
```

Try applying parenthesis to the various expressions and that should resolve it.

P.S. you may want to look at using intervals to simplify this:

```
let d = 6.5
if !(1...5).contains(d) {
    println("d not within range")
}
```

Comment: I will see if adding parenthesis works when I get home, thank you for the answer!